# What's the best between return the result and print it at the end of the function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, coding-style

Assume we define a function and then end it with:

```
def function():
     # ...
     return result
# To see the result, we need to type:
print(function())
```

Another option is to end a function with a `print`:

```
def function():
     # ...
     print(result)

# no need of print at the call anymore so
function()
```

**Question:** May I end function with a `return` statement, get it via `function()` or not?
I mean I don't care whether function saves the result or not. However the function can have several different results, i.e I need to quit the loop at some point. The main idea is to get the output on the screen.
So, let me know please whether my variant is OK or it's not 'elegant' coding. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **most cleaner way is with the `return` statement**. In general, a function returns a result, and this result can be processed after by another algorithm. Maybe you don't need to get the result in a variable in your case, but imagine you do in 1 week, month...

The best way is to delegate the `print` at the main program itself. You'll manage data in your program more easily and, as I said, you can chain functions.

Imagine two functions `a(arg)` and `b(arg)` that returns two calculations. With the `print` statement in the `b` function, you'll not be able to do this:

```
a(b(10))
```

because `a` will receive a `None` value in argument (because functions returns `None` by default, which is the case with the `print` statement at the end).

**TL;DR**: Follow this pattern most of the time:

```
def get_full_name(arg1, arg2, ...):
    # Do cool stuff
    return res   # <- result of the function


print get_full_name('foo', 'bar')
full_name = get_full_name('Maxime', 'Lorant')
print some_other_function(full_name)
# etc.
```

Comment: Many thanks, Maxime. Your example is the most reasonable so far.

Answer (score 10):

If you `return print(result)`, you're essentially doing `return None` because `print()` returns `None`. So that doesn't make much sense.

I'd say it's much cleaner to `return result` and have the caller decide whether to `print()` it or do whatever else with it.

Comment: Of course I tried it =))) Everything works as I expect, I just wonder if it's elegant solution or not.

Comment: @Olga +1 for trying it; you wouldn’t believe how many people are asking questions without trying it out themselves first ;)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, however I have just found that I didn't assume the case which was illustrated by @Maxime Lorant. Then my variant doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function will not return anything; it will only print the stuff as output to the console. So returning the return value from the `print` function does not really make much sense. You are returning nothing by definition.

So unless you want to end the function early, there is no reason why you should use `return` in this case. Just printing the result (without using `return`) is fine and a lot clearer.

Also, if you want to return the actual content the `print` function prints, then you should just do that instead and leave it to the caller to decide whether to print it or not.

If you want to use `print(function())` (which to me sounds the most reasonable here), then just return the result from the function:

```
def function ():
    # ...
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about printing it you should just do:

`print(result)`

at the end of the function, but generally if you are trying to use the result then just return it and then you can use the result and print it

you probably shouldn't do `return print(result)` just do either or print it outside the function

if you use `return print(result)` you aren't returning anything so its pointless

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. When you call a function the value return is print() (not value of result)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a keyword argument that will be a switch of whether of not you want the result printed before returning from your function:

```
def func(arg1, arg2,verbose=True):
    # do cool stuff
    # 'result' is what it all produced
    if verbose:
        print result
    return result
```

Then just call `func(arg1,arg2,...,verbose=False)` to turn it off.